# WCF Transport Security

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I am trying to implement WCF Transport security.
i have already done the configuration part. ie set the binding security mode, enabled https and ClientCredentialType.
my services are hosted in a console application.
i have created a certificate using makecert.exe.
what should i do next?
how should i let my web application and services use the certificate?
is there any iis configuration i should do?

Comment: So your website is the wcf client?  What do your config files look like?

Comment: yes my website is the wcf client...

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the service port with the certificate. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx) for details.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You are self-hosting, so IIS does not come into play.

Comment: IIS is the _client_ here, you'll have to convince that Computer to trust the cert.